# Love someone for sake of Allah

Tags: islamic-philosophy

Assalamu alaikum wr wb,
Can someone explain what is love someone for sake of Allah?
Jazakallahu khairan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When loving one helps for nearness to Allah it is loving for sake of Allah.

The best example for this is loving messenger of Allah Muhammad SAWW.

As an example lets assume you love a person. but do not know his/her address. and there is only one person who can guide you to reach your beloved one. so you love the guide for sake of your beloved.

As another example if one loves a branch of knowledge loves the professors of that branch for sake of that knowledge. in fact those professors are the way of reaching that beloved knowledge.